# Cannot create a custom com.facebook.Request.Callback

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I send a Graph API request as follow:

```
Request request = new Request(session, graphPath, params, HttpMethod.GET, new CustomCallBack());
```

In which my CustomCallBack implements the **com.facebook.Request.Callback**:

```
private class CustomCallBack implements Callback{

    public CustomCallBack(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

    }

}
```

It announced error like

> Illegal modifier for the local class CustomCallBack; only abstract or final is 
>    permitted

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/publish-to-feed/#step3
from the example there you can see that Callback is interface in Request.
change class header to

public class YourCallback implements Request.Callback